# What is this use of auto ? - ADL?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have always thought that `auto` should be used in the following form `auto varName = someOtherVar;`. Today I have found that I could also use `auto varName(someOtherVar);`. At first I thought that maybe this is Argument Depending Lookup at work. But I am not sure. What are the restrictions for using such auto syntax? Below is some code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Person {
    public:
    Person(std::string s) : name(s) {}
    Person(const Person& p) : name(p.name) {}
    std::string name;
};

int main()
{
    Person p("hello");
    auto p2(p); // equivalent to auto p2 = p; ?
    std::cout << p2.name;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) may be used in place of the type specifier in a declaration with initializer; then the type is deduced from the initializer.

`T a = b;` is called [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization)  , `T a(b);` is called [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization)  , there are subtle differences.

So `auto p2(p);` is the same as `Person p2(p);`.  Since the initializer has the same type as the object being initialized, copy-initialization and direct-initialization are identical in this case.

"Argument-dependent lookup" refers to resolving the scope of a function name. But this is an object declaration, not a function call.  (There is ADL on the line `std::cout << p2.name;` though - `operator<<` resolves via ADL to `std::operator<<`).

Comment: And don't forget `new auto(p)` either.

Comment: @NicolBolas Personally I would rather forget about that..:)